# jpa @manytoone creates composite primary key instead of @id

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, many-to-one

I am running spring jpa project and I have following class containing @ManyToOne relations:

```
    package ba.fit.vms.pojo;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.Date;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

    import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="korisnik_vozilo")
    public class KorisnikVozilo implements Serializable{

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="id")
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER )
        @JoinColumn(nullable=false, updatable=false)
        private Vozilo vozilo;

        @ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER )
        @JoinColumn(nullable=false, updatable=false)
        private Korisnik korisnik;

        @Column(name = "dodijeljeno")
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        @NotNull
        private Date dodijeljeno;

        @Column(name = "vraceno")
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private Date vraceno;

        ...

    }
```

For some reason, starting the server, this code creates composite primary key (korisnik_id,vozilo_vin), instead of @Id defined primary key. Here is the screenshot of the table:[image: table view]
Can someone explain to me what did I do wrong and how to write this code so I do not get this composite key in the database, but the one defined in the class.

It even sets autoincrement on korisnik_id!

Comment: offtopic comment: a general good practice is not to name fields and classes in your native language

Comment: what is your jpa implementation/

Comment: I use Spring sts to implement Spring data jpa **hibenate** mysql

Comment: and you use hbm2ddl.auto=true?

Comment: hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of `updatable=false`. being unupdatable, the two columns might be be viewed as an immutable identity of the entity.

Comment: Removed it, deleted the table, saved the class and restarted the server. Unfortunately, same result.

Answer (score 0):

You may check how you can use `@JoinColumn` to solve your problem.

Comment: Any links or suggestions?

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/ check this also the hibernate reference explains all annotations with example very nicely http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#example.collection.mapping.annotations